# Debugger tool for Kaa Application with Kaa C SDK

Tags: c, debugging, sdk, raspberry-pi, kaa

I need to try with debugging Kaa application by Kaa C SDK for Raspberry Pi.

For example: Cassandra data analytics demo.

**1-** Please, suggest to me the best debugger tool, and

**2-** How can I import and setup project with debugger tool.

**Note:** I can do it with simple way just put **"printf"** function and then seeing the result, But I need a debugger tool.

Answer (score 1):

This question is not Kaa specific, as it is just a regular C application, so you can use any debugging tool you know.

1. The default debugging tool for Linux is [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/), though you can use any graphical GDB interface you like. For example, you can use [KDbg](http://www.kdbg.org/), Emacs plugin, or any other C IDE. (Refer to you tool documentation for further instructions.)
2. To enable debugging, it is recommended to enable debug symbol generation in CMake and disable optimizations. This is done with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` CMake flag.